# Shell Script Need to run as a root user

Tags: linux, shell, permissions, ownership

I have shell scripts like below for changing/switch to another ISP connection.

```
#!/bin/bash
/sbin/route add default gw 192.168.1
/sbin/route del default gw 192.168.1.2
/sbin/route del default gw 192.168.1.3
/sbin/route -n
```

I have root access to my Ubuntu machine but I need to run the above shell script as a normal user. How can I do that?

**NOTE:**

*Case-1:* Our local machine login to LDAP server, so I can't add my Linux username to sudoers/visudo.

*Case-2:* I have already move that script to /bin directory and added the SUID special permission to my script. But the normal user can't run this script.

Comment: Are you getting any error in case 2?

Comment: Consider sudo (why do you think that’s not an option?), setuid is not supported for scripts.

Comment: [How to run Bash script as root with no password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/167847), [How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18830/56041), [How do I sudo a command in a script without being asked for a password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/155791), [How to make a script run commands as root](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29224136/608639), [How do I run a 'sudo' command inside a script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/425754), *ad nauseum* ...

Comment: See also the various questions about "how do I make my PHP script shoot myself in the foot with root access without running the HTTP server as root", some of which contain hacks which work around the `sudo` requirement.

Comment: I am getting the following following error when I run the script:

    SIOCADDRT: Operation not permitted
    SIOCDELRT: Operation not permitted

I may not think the sudo is working fine for my case. Because our user account created in an LDAP server.Due to this reason the local my user account is not found in my local machine. I don't have any LDAP server access. If I want to add the the username to sudo/sudoers/visudo I need an account in the local machine, right?

Answer (score 0):

I was fixed the issue. Fix method is follows:

Added SUID permission to the route command and added execute permission to that shell script and moved file to /bin directory.Now you can run the script as command.